# PHP - 500 instead of error

Tags: php

I have a page written in PHP. I do not have access to the server. I'd like to make so that instead of showing an error message when PHP encounters an error, it gives a 500.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I think OP is referring to the HTTP Status code 500.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP 5.2 by default sends HTTP 500 in case of fatal error, if display_errors is off.
If the hosting is with older PHP, you have to register your own [error handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler) and possibly [exception handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler) and redirect the user to your 500 error page. Try setting the display_errors and error_reporting variables in your PHP script as @Umang suggested.

Answer (score 2):

you can create your own error handler and use it to send 503 status code to the client.