# PHP server error in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am in Ubuntu 11.10. When I write a simple script like `echo phpinfo();` it runs and shows no error. But if I try to write some extra php code the browser server error page. What is the issue here I dont understand ??

Lets say if I change the code to the following it gives server error;

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    private $prop;
    public function __construct(){
        echo "The class \"".__CLASS__."\"was created";
    }
    public function __destruct(){
        echo "The class \"".__CLASS__."\" was destroyed";   
    }
    protected function getProperty(){
        return $prop;
    }
    public function __toString(){
        echo "__toString() method called.<br />";
        return $this->getProperty().'<br />';
    }
    public function setProperty($prop){
        $this->prop = $prop;
    }
}
class MyOtherClass extends MyClass{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__contruct();
        echo "A new constructor in class \"".__CLASS__"\"";
    }
    public function newMethod(){
        echo 'From a new method in class '.__CLASS__.'<br />';
    }
}
$newClass = new MyOtherClass();
echo $newClass->getProperty();
?>
```

Comment: could you provide a code sample please?

Comment: What is the Sever Error?

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyClass{
    protected getProperty(){
    //...

    public __toString(){
    //...

    public setProperty($prop){
    //...

class MyOtherClass extends MyClass{
    public __construct(){
    // ...
```

You're missing `function` after `public`/`protected` in several methods.

---

Couple more errors:

```
class MyOtherClass extends MyClass{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__contruct();
        echo "A new constructor in class \"".__CLASS__"\"";
    }
    //...
```

- You misspelled `parent::_construct()` without the `s`.
- In your `echo` line, `__CLASS__` is missing a `.` concatenation operator after it.

  `echo $newClass->getProperty();`
- `MyClass::getProperty()` is `protected`, so you can't call it from out here.

Comment: Even if I had mistakes in code PHP interpreter should respond me with the errors. Anyways, I have edited the code above and the same error persists.

Comment: Sometimes PHP errors actually do cause 500 server errors, based on server setup. What's in the error log?

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request

Comment: @insane-36 I meant the PHP error log. Also check php.ini to make sure logging is enabled first.

Comment: @insane-36 Perhaps this will help? [HTTP Error 500 Internal server for php pages](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/http-error-500-internal-server-for-php-pages-and-solution.html)

Comment: I am not sure where to look inside php.ini.

Comment: @insane-36 Here are relevant configuration options: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5638/discussion-between-insane-36-and-wiseguy)

Comment: @insane-36 Does it work after you fix the additional errors I mentioned? Also see this question: [PHP - 500 instead of error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301573/php-500-instead-of-error).