# 500 Server error instead of display parse error

Tags: php, parse-error

I receive 500 error message when there is a parse error in my coding.

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was
>   encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Hosting Service: **bluehost**.

I want to see the error instead of 500 server error.

Also, I am using WordPress for running my website.

How can we do that?

I have also read following articles but didn't got anything.
[How can I make PHP display the error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)
[PHP - 500 instead of error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301573/php-500-instead-of-error)

Comment: 500 server error comes when you have any error in configuration instead of any coding error.

Comment: Follow the best answer in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error

Comment: @DeadMan Not necessarily. I get plenty of 500s when setting up one of my company's sites locally sometimes, and they all end up being PHP errors

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Error Log` in the cPanel menu. It will have all of the details there.